# Why image goes out of borders in ImageButton with rounded corners?

Tags: android, xml, imageview, imagebutton

I have ImageButton with background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
</shape>
```

But when I add src to the ImageButton, an Image goes out of borders.
Without src:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
    android:id="@+id/photo"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/bgPhoto"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:background="@drawable/profile_photo_too_roundcorner"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"/>
```

[image]

With src:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
    android:id="@+id/photo"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/bgPhoto"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:background="@drawable/profile_photo_too_roundcorner"
    android:src="@drawable/plus_photo"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"/>
```

[image]

Comment: In your case you can use a simple FloatingActionButton or a circular [MaterialButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58529593/how-to-create-a-circular-outlined-material-button-in-android/58529735#58529735)

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti then there will be another image

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I found your another answer and it helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/60058794/11400177