# How to create circle button, change its colour and animate it with Material Design themes Android?

Tags: android, animation, button, geometry, material-design

I am trying to create a circle button (not a rounded square), with a different colour and wish for it to animate with a pulsing yellow aura when it is clicked.

I am using the latest version of Android Studio (4.1.2) which includes Material Design Components themes automatically.

What's the updated way to achieve this sort of button? I've read that changing the background resource of a button is outdated which is what I see a lot in Google results ([How to make buttons rounded with Material Design Theming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61054834/how-to-make-buttons-rounded-with-material-design-theming)).

Comment: For the circular button check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58529593/how-to-create-a-circular-outlined-material-button-in-android/58529735#58529735

Answer (score 0):

You can use always use a material card view or a regular card view, and if you set the radius exactly the half of its height it will be rounded, beware there is a chance if you have multiline text it will get cut off, for the effect you can define a selector with different states.